# Putting excel in the WPF datagrid gives me strange time

Tags: wpf

this is my code

```
if (ofdl.ShowDialog() == true) {
  if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(ofdl.FileName) == ".xlsx" ||
      System.IO.Path.GetExtension(ofdl.FileName) == ".xls") {
    try { //엑셀읽기
      dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      xl = new Excel.Application();
      xlwork = xl.Workbooks.Open(ofdl.FileName);
      xlsheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlwork.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
      Excel.Range range = xlsheet.UsedRange;
      Array myvalue = (Array)range.Cells.Value2;
      int vertical = myvalue.GetLength(0);
      int horizon = myvalue.GetLength(1);
      under_label.Content = ofdl.FileName;

      //   Excel.Range range = xlsheet.Cells[] as Excel.Range;
      object[, ] data = range.Value2;

      for (int cnt = 1; cnt <= range.Columns.Count; cnt++) {
        str = Convert.ToString(data[1, cnt]);
        if (str == "" || str == null)
          break;
        dt.Columns.Add(str);
      }

      for (int cnt2 = 2; cnt2 <= range.Rows.Count; cnt2++) {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        for (int cnt3 = 1; cnt3 <= range.Columns.Count; cnt3++) {
          value = Convert.ToString(data[cnt2, cnt3]);

          if (cnt3 == 1) {
            if (value == "" || value == null) {
              cnt2 = range.Rows.Count;
            }
          }
          dr[cnt3 - 1] = value;
        }

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        under_label1.Content = "항목" + dt.Rows.Count + "개";
      }
      // xlsheet.range[xlsheet.cells[시작 행, 시작 열], xlsheet.cells[끝행,
      // 끝열]]

      xlwork.Close(true);
      xl.Quit();
      dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

excel ex) 2019:09:12 09:14:45

datagrid ) 45678.1234

i don't know how to change date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its OLE Automation value, Just convert the value to DateTime.

`double d = double.Parse(b);
DateTime convertedDateTime = DateTime.FromOADate(d);`

Comment: I solved the problem.
But not this way
I replaced VALUE2 with VALUE and it resolved

Comment: there is another way to do this, you can you OLEDB data reader to read the content from excel. you need not to do any conversion if you do this